# How do I run chromium inside a chroot?

Tags: chrome, chroot, thunderbird, iceweasel

Okay, I can run Iceweasel 17 ESR fine and some simple X apps like xkill, so I know that it's not merely an X display problem. However any version of Chromium and Iceweasel 24 fail with the following errors respectively:

```
mikoto@localhost:~$ chromium 
[12031:12031:1010/111246:FATAL:zygote_host_impl_linux.cc(73)] Check failed: PathService::Get(base::FILE_EXE, &chrome_path). 
Aborted
mikoto@localhost:~$ iceweasel 
(process:12035): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_slice_set_config: assertion `sys_page_size == 0' failed
```

I'm using the standard Debian chroot environment produced by `sudo debootstrap --variant=minbase --arch=i386 unstable chroot` on a x86-64 system without any 32-bit compatibility libs installed. I can't run wine or the Google Android SDK directly on my base system, but I've extracted some of the tools into my 32-bit chroot and they run fine.

Note that the Iceweasel 24 error message above appears to be non-fatal since I can find that line even when running Iceweasel 24 successfully on my base system. By "non-fatal", I mean the error message, despite the ominous "CRITICAL" tag, most likely doesn't provide a clue as to why Iceweasel 24 won't run. This is confirmed by the few hours of web searching I spent using the error message as a keyword. So, besides spitting out this error message, Iceweasel 24 fails silently.

I'm posing this as a chromium question since I suspect anything that fixes the Chromium startup failure will also fix Iceweasel 24.

Comment: What exactly is then happening to Iceweasel 24? Does it hang?

Comment: What Window Manager are you running in your chroot env? Neither iceweasel or chromium will run without the X-server running a WM.

Comment: To merge your two accounts, see http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts