# Google Chrome not working in Debian wheezy chroot

Tags: debian, chrome, schroot

I have a wheezy chroot running on squeeze, using `schroot`.  I'm successfully using Skype.  I've installed `google-chrome-stable_current_i386.deb` (version 38) in the chroot but when I try to run it, it exits immediately and says `Aborted`.  I ran it with `strace` which indicates this is because it received `SIG_ABORT`.

When I run `google-chrome-stable --disable-setuid-sandbox` it works, but complains about stability and security.  (Obviously it's using a sandbox for a reason.)

I suspect I'm having the same issue as [How do I run chromium inside a chroot?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/94423/how-do-i-run-chromium-inside-a-chroot).